# Trying to set an audio asset as a ringtone on Android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm using the following package to set a an audio asset as a ringtone
[ringtone_set](https://github.com/rtacr/ringtone_set)

This is the error I keep encountering when calling the setRingtone method.

```
W/System.err(15204): java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
W/System.err(15204):    at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:128)
W/System.err(15204):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1229)
W/System.err(15204):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:1009)
W/System.err(15204):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openOutputStream(ContentResolver.java:985)
W/System.err(15204):    at acr.rt.ringtone_set.RingtoneSetPlugin.setThings(RingtoneSetPlugin.java:109)
W/System.err(15204):    at acr.rt.ringtone_set.RingtoneSetPlugin.onMethodCall(RingtoneSetPlugin.java:151)
W/System.err(15204):    at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:233)
W/System.err(15204):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.handleMessageFromDart(DartMessenger.java:85)
W/System.err(15204):    at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterJNI.java:692)
W/System.err(15204):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err(15204):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
W/System.err(15204):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:151)
W/System.err(15204):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6724)
W/System.err(15204):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err(15204):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
W/System.err(15204):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:810)
```

I am using another package to request permissions to access the users storage.
If the library can't find the asset then it will log a message to the console.  I can play the sound just fine as well, its just when I try to set the ringtone.

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.anisoundboard2">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Here is how I am loading the assets in `pubspec.yaml`

```
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/
    - assets/sounds/
```

Here is the function that is called when the user clicks Set as Ringtone

```
  Future setRingtone(String soundFileName) async {
    try {
      await requestStoragePermission();
      await RingtoneSet.setRingtone('assets/sounds/$soundFileName');
    } catch(e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

And this is the function I use to request permission

```
  Future requestStoragePermission() async {
    final status = await Permission.storage.request();
    print(status);
  }
```

This worked on my Android Emulator, but I am currently testing on an actual device.  The LG Phoenix 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says that there is an error in URI and you need to fix it (URI is null).

Possible solutions:

1. Check the URI and the sound file name.
2. If it's working on emulator but not on the phone, check the OS version of both of them.
3. You might get the permissions in just one `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Apply it on both `AndroidManifest.xml` files in `debug` and `release` folders.

Comment: After going off these recommendations, I discovered that works on Android 10.0 and up.  So now I just don't render the set ringtone button if the version is too low.  Thank you for your insight

Answer (score -1):

Use [this](https://github.com/Hakim-Allaoui/ringtone_set) pull request, The error is fixed. The last commit has some bug.

Comment: you should have commented this instead of posting an answer.

Comment: I actually did use this one, the bug was not fixed